# Assembler instructions to modify the return address within the called function

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit

I'm quite new to assembler, and I still do not know most of the instructions.

I am trying to add some asm lines to a C program (just for fun, playing with it) to modify the return address of a function.

The C code looks like

```
int my_function()
{
    int my_number = 1;

    __asm__ ("nop"); 
    __asm__ ("nop"); 

    return my_number;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    //declarations

    ...lots of stuff

    int my_number = my_function();

    do_something;

    ...lots of stuff

    do_other_thing;

    ... lots of stuff (46 bits in assembler)

    return 0;
}
```

so, what I try to do, is to modify the return address in the stack once on `my_function` so, when returning, it goes to `do_other_thing` instead of going to `do_something`

To make it nice, and dynamically, I prefer to not hard-code the return address, so I will like to add those 46 bits. I know also the return address is in `EBP + 4`. I have tested it manually within `x32dgb`, and it works.

I guess I will have to:

1. get the content pointed by EBP + 4 (maybe in EAX)
2. sum 46 to EAX
3. write back this value into the EBP + 4

so far I have understand it, but not sure how to code this into ASM sentences ...

may you help me??

Comment: In `my_function()` you could do an `add dword [EBP+4], x` with x=46 bits. But 46 bits is most likely wrong... Maybe 46 bytes or something - whatever the difference between after the call and `do_other_thing` will be.

Comment: And make sure that the compiler option [-fomit-frame-pointer](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/704809) is not active.

Comment: GCC has `__builtin_return_address(0)` to *read* the current function's return address ( [How can I determine the return address on stack?](//stackoverflow.com/q/1693011)).  I thought I remembered a builtin to get the *address of* the return address, so you could modify it with C, but I can't any such thing.  That kind of makes sense, you should probably write context-switch functions in pure asm.  There's very little you could usefully do with such a thing without asm, and writing a whole function in asm means you don't have to save/restore the call-clobbered registers.

Comment: @zx485 that would be a beautiful solution, but it doesn't work in my case, something on syntax  ??

Comment: Error: junk `[ebp+4]' after expression

Comment: Error: too many memory references for `add'

Comment: __asm__("add dword [ebp+4], (4)");

Comment: @gokunef Gcc uses AT&T style assembly for it's inline assembly.  If you want to use inline assembly, you have to learn that new syntax.  For example, `add dword [ebp+4], 4` is `add $4, 4(%ebp)`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just be careful with the codification and symbols into your C

as @zx489 mention, try something like:

```
__asm__(".intel_syntax prefix");
__asm__("add dword ptr [%ebp + 4], 46");
```

that may work...

Comment: Requires `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` (which is only the default at `-O0`).  And of course also requires `__attribute__((noinline))` on the function.  Also, you need to set the mode back to AT&T unless you compiled with `-masm=intel`.  Using intel syntax with prefix is super weird, and will always break the rest of the compiler's code-gen.  (unless this is the last function in the file, and there's only a leave/ret after this.)

Answer (score 5):

> I am trying to add some asm lines to a C program (just for fun, playing with it) to modify the return address of a function.

Don't.

For code written in C; the compiler owns the stack, the compiler generates function startup code to suit itself and its optimisations, and the compiler generates exit code to suit its own startup code. Any inline assembly that makes any assumptions about the stack layout is "fragile" - a tiny change anywhere (even just changing an innocent local variable, changing a compiler command line arg, or updating the compiler to the next version) can and eventually will cause differences in the layout of the stack which will break the inline assembly. In practice it's actually far worse than that - compiler can and will generate multiple different versions of the same "C function" (and inline some versions into other functions to avoid the cost of a function call, etc), so that you end up with the same piece of inline assembly that's trying (and guaranteed to be failing) to handle multiple completely different stack layouts; and even if you do successfully return somewhere else you can't reliably avoid screwing everything up after your function returned.

The other problem is that there's almost never a sane reason to want to do this in the first place; even if you're writing assembly language where you have complete control over the stack layout (and not writing C with inline assembly language where you have no control of the stack layout).

Essentially; there are an extremely large number of things that are more important for someone trying to learn assembly to spend their time learning (that aren't "fragile" and aren't useless). This is like learning how to drive a car while standing on your hands (using your face on the accelerator/brake pedals and not being able to see anything around you) - it's not useful.

Comment: I'm one of the upvotes. I'd recommend a link to @DavidWohlferd article at gnu.org: [Don't use inline Asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)

Comment: "The other problem is that there's almost never a sane reason to want to do this in the first place; even if you're writing assembly language where you have complete control over the stack layout (and not writing C with inline assembly language where you have no control of the stack layout)."

Comment: for fun, just playing, learning, education, I think those are plausible reason, isn't it?

Comment: I understand your point, I will never do this into production environment , thanks for the link,

Comment: @gokunef I do understand these reasons.  However, inline assembly is not designed for this sort of thing and trying to do it anyway is an extremely frustrating experience (been there, done that).  Instead I recommend you to write your entire function in assembly and to assemble it with an assembler of choice.

Comment: I read once again the responses you have give me, and make me think whats the way to understand asm. Following some notes and exercises come with that of hacking a function within itself, the question I post upwards. But not responses left me a little out of my place. **I am doing something worthless?** (I must admit that I am very new on asm)

Comment: Maybe this is not the place for a philosophical discussion, (we can take it outside, je je). But yes, indeed, I you have a minute to discuss it, I will be very happy to do it. I have a sense that most programmers (and programming courses) just teach how to put brick over brick, but don't know what a house is for.

Comment: @gokunef So the point is that to use inline assembly effectively, you need to be both (a) a good assembly programmer and (b) very familiar with how the compiler generates code.  The compiler is no longer a simple machine that translates your code line by line.  It is a very complicated beast that does all sorts of transformations including (a) using any register it likes (b) moving your code around as it likes (c) duplicating your code (which is why you have to be careful with labels in inline assembly) and (d) assuming that you don't do anything weird in inline assembly. (1/2)

Comment: Now what you want to do is pretty much impossible because there are so many ways the compiler could decide to lay out your function.  Just because you get it to work with one compiler version and one set of compiler flags, doesn't mean that it's going to work any time in the future or if you change the slightest bit of your code.  That's because fundamentally, your code is making wrong assumptions and is thus broken.  There is little gained by learning how to write broken code and some programmers mistakingly assume that their code is not actually broken because it works on their machine.

Comment: And herein lies the danger.  It is much easier to learn assembly programming if you don't start with trying to meddle with the compiler or break programs.  These are advanced topic and for a good reason.  Start with the basic stuff: write your own assembly code in assembly source files and learn how all of this works.  Once you are deeply familiar with assembly and the workings of the compiler, you can try to do weird things.

Answer (score 1):

Using inline assembly seems to be quite dangerous, as is mentioned by @Brendan:

> For code written in C; the compiler owns the stack, the compiler generates function startup code to suit itself and its optimisations, and the compiler generates exit code to suit its own startup code. Any inline assembly that makes any assumptions about the stack layout is "fragile"...

But **with the assumption** that "the return address being placed right above the stack frame of the current function", maybe you can try something like this:

```
void foo(void)
{
    uintptr_t *p_return_address = __builtin_frame_address(0) + sizeof(size_t);
    *p_return_address = /* the new return address */;
}
```

Nevertheless, if `foo` doesn't return to its caller due to the modified return address, the epilogue of the caller will never be executed, and in turn causing many other nasty problems, such as stack overflow. So, this is still a very dangerous thing to do.